# newgrp command not working correctly while switching to another group

Tags: linux

I have just got a issue from the user where  `newgrp` command is not working while swicthing to the the other group from the primary group.

But when user is trying to switch it show it has been switched to the new_group which they needed and while doing `id -g` it showing the new_group ID as well but when user trying to create a file or directory it shows the group ownership of `primary group` Below is details ...

> # newgrp other_group
>
> # id -g  <-- this show the goup id of the other_group which we want to use

```
  [ kk-uat1 ~]$ id
    uid=252498(uat1) gid=1205(kamm) groups=1198(tamm),1205(kamm)

        [ kk-uat1 ~]$ newgrp tamm
        [ kk-uat1 ~]$ id -g
        1198


        [ kk-uat1 ~]$ touch test1
        [ kk-uat1 ~]$ ls -ltrh test1
        -rw-r--r-- 1 uat1 kamm 0 Jan  1 23:20 test1
```

So, in the above test, even after switching to group tamm with `newgrp` command it creats the files with primary group ownership `kamm`

Comment: Maybe the `setgid` bit is set on the folder permissions? This says that all new files created in the folder are owned by the same group as the folder itself: `ls -ld .` would show an `s` instead of `x` at the group permissions.

Comment: @ridgy your point is good.